# Why $\pi$ // Rationalize does not give a rational multiple of $\pi$ in my example?

Tags: numerics, big-numbers

As an obvious example of `π Rationalize`, I see that

```
a := 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693521632 

π  Rationalize[N[a]/π ]

(* π *)
```

but when I try this way for another rational multiple of $\pi$, it does not give a rational multiple of $\pi$

```
b :=   (12343556574747/50000) π

π  Rationalize[N[b]/π ]

(* 7.75569*10^8 *)
```

I expected an answer the same as the original number $b$. Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong?

More precisely, I want to use this method to check whether the following number

$2.47518811442233432405585032549718484885918373175315936866881011953607\
8273196602710715450734911249987$

is a rational multiple of $\pi$ or not.

Comment: Checkout the second bullet point in the Details section of the [ref page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html).

Comment: @ChipHurst fun thing. You can link directly there: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html#78212097

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I want to show that without hypotheses, the problem of determining whether $x=a/\pi$ came from a rational number is unsolvable. But, spoiler alert, the OP's number `2.47...` is probably not a rational multiple of `Pi` or it is not precise enough to determine whether it is.

---

First, a floating-point number $x$ comes with an uncertainty $dx$. If $x$ comes from rounding a rational number $y$ to the nearest floating-point number, then we have
$$x-dx \le y \le x+dx \,.$$
In Mathematica, $dx$ is given roughly by

```
dx = x * 10.^-Precision[x]
```

I say "roughly" because $dx$ will be a power of $2$ and the left and right uncertainties can be asymmetric at the boundaries where the floating-point exponent changes.  For instance, if $y$ rounds to $1$ in the current [binary64 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for machine precision (double precision), then we have $1-2^{-54} \le y \le 1+2^{-53}$.

Second, the rational numbers are dense in the real numbers, which means there are infinitely many rational numbers $\tilde y$ such that
$$x-dx \le \tilde y \le x+dx \,. \tag{1}$$

---

The problem is this: ***Given that we know $x$ (and therefore $dx$), find the rational number $y$ from among the infinitely many $\tilde y$ satisfying (1).***  It is impossible, since too much information was lost when $y$ was rounded.

A solvable problem is this: ***Find the rational number $\tilde y$ satisfying (1) with the smallest denominator.*** This problem is solved in *Mathematica* by any of these calls:

```
yy = Rationalize[x, dx]
yy = Rationalize[x, 0]   (* uses the precision of x to determine dx *)
yy = Last@Convergents[x] (* uses the continued fraction expansion of x *)
```

---

*Example.*
Let's take a simpler version of the OP's second problem, without the `Pi`, which is a red herring anyway.

```
brat = (12343556574747/50000); (* == b/Pi *)
x = N[brat];
dx = x * 10.^-Precision[x];
yy = Rationalize[x, dx]
Rationalize[x, 0]
Last@Convergents[x]

(*  1048955437722  /  4249  *)
```

There is no way to infer from `x` that the original denominator was `50000`.  It should be clear that `yy` is not the closest fraction, just the one with the smallest denominator within the uncertainty `dx`.  In fact `brat` is closer to `x` than `yy`.  One might think there is still hope to recover `brat` from `x`, but there is not.

A continued fraction convergent of `x` gives the rational number closest to `x` that has a denominator smaller than the denominator of the next convergent.  We will see from the convergents of `x` that there is always a better choice of a fraction than `brat`.

Let's look at the number `x`.  It is a fraction of the form $x_0/2^n$, which we can get using `SetPrecision`:

```
xx = SetPrecision[x, Infinity]

(*  8283620594510023 / 33554432  <-- x0/2^25 *)
```

Here are some of the convergents related to our problem. Since we have converted `x` to an infinite-precision fraction, we get more convergents:

```
Convergents[xx][[6 ;; 11]]
(*
  {  268348919935  /   1087,
    1048955437722  /   4249,  <-- smallest at mach. prec.
    1317304357657  /   5336,
    2366259795379  /   9585,
   10782343539173  /  43676,  <-- best with denom. < 140612
   34713290412898  / 140613}
*)
```

So if you knew that the denominator was between, say, `10000` and `100000`, the best approximation is not `brat`, but `10782343539173/43676`.  What we hoped to recover turns out to be a less than optimal solution.  I have no idea how to choose the correct solution from among all the less than optimal ones. I don't think it can be done.

---

Finally, we can come to a way to solve this problem, assuming $x$ is a good enough approximation of $y$.  In general rational numbers are harder to approximate by rational numbers (other than themselves) than irrational numbers.  We can use this to determine when a number is probably a rational number.  (I am not an expert in this field: I do not know whether there is a way to assign a probability to the result.)

`Rationalize[x]` solves the problem if the denominator of $y=p/q$ satisfies the criterion given in the docs:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The left-hand side of the inequality is $dx = |y-x|$.  The exponent $2$ shows up in various [Diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) theorems. The most elementary is
$$\left| {p' \over q'} - {p \over q} \right| \ge {1 \over q'q} \ge {1 \over \mathop{\text{min}}(q',q)^2}\,.$$
From this we can infer on condition `x` should satisfy: Since the a small error in the denominator of `x` implies the error in approximating `y = p/q` is at least around `1/q^2`, we should have

```
Accuracy[x] >= 2 Log10[q]
```

Then there are [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) and its generalizations:  For an irrational $y$, there are infinitely many coprime integers $p'$ and $q'>0$ such that
$$\left| {p' \over q'} - y \right| \le {c \over (q')^2} \,,$$
where the constant $c = 1$ is Dirchlet's theorem.  See [Diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) for more.

For a rational number, the error scaled by square of the denominator should be large, except once, when the error is zero.  If $x \approx p/q$, then one might expect the scaled error $(q')^2\left| {p' / q'} - x \right|$  will be small only once, provided $x$ is a good enough approximation. (Since we're changing $y$ to $x$, this needs proof, which I haven't done, but it seems to hold computationally.)  On the other hand, an irrational number will have several peaks in the scaled error.

Here's a look at some known irrational numbers:

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
 convE = Convergents[E, 100];
 scerrE = (E - convE) Denominator[convE]^2;
 convPi = Convergents[Pi, 100];
 scerrPi = (Pi - convPi) Denominator[convPi]^2;
 conv2 = Convergents[10 Sqrt[2], 100];
 scerr2 = (10 Sqrt[2] - conv2) Denominator[conv2]^2;
 ListLinePlot[RealExponent@{scerrE, scerrPi, scerr2}
  , PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> {E, Pi, 10 Sqrt[2]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Here's an approximation of a rational number, similar to the problem in the OP. There's a shallow "peak" in 5th convergent, similar in magnitude to the irrational numbers above. This is followed by deep spike, followed by a large jump. It is so large because it is scaled by `q^2`, where `q` is the denominator of the 11th convergent; therefore `1/q` will be less than the rounding error in `x = N[y]`, and the jump in scaled error will be greater than `Accuracy[x]`.

```
x = N[12346/33333 Pi, 30]/Pi;
conv = Convergents[SetPrecision[x, Infinity]];
scerr = (x - conv) Denominator[conv]^2;
ListLinePlot[RealExponent@scerr
 , PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

There's a disturbing issue in the behavior of `Convergents[x]`. It doesn't find the approximation we seek.   Apparently we need to increase the precision of `x`.

```
Convergents[x]
Convergents[SetPrecision[x, Infinity]]
(*
  {0, 1/2, 1/3, 3/8, 10/27, 1023/2762, 1033/2789, 2056/5551, 5145/13891}

  {0, 1/2, 1/3, 3/8, 10/27, 1023/2762, 1033/2789, 2056/5551, 5145/13891, 
   12346/33333, 
   192070822042862116379943873/518572550717213909387062135, 
   ...10 fractions omitted...,
   939034248967552886981567682091/2535301200456458802993406410752}
*)
```

The deep spike is at the desired fraction `12346/33333`.  This should be typical when $x$ is a good approximation to $y$.

---

If we put the ideas above together we can write a function `findRationalMultiples[x, m]` that will return a rational multiple of `m` in the form `{p * m / q}`, if `x` seems to be a rational multiple of `m`.  It returns an empty list `{}` if `x` appears not to be a rational multiple of `m`.  It may also return a list of rational multiples, depending on the parameters to `PeakDetect[]`. If `x` is a rational multiple of `m`, then the last element of the list is probably the correct answer; but such cases should be examined carefully.

The call `findRationalMultiples[{x, m}, sm, sh, th]` passes the smoothing, sharpness, and threshold parameters to `PeakDetect[]`.
The call `findRationalMultiples[{x, m}, sm, sh, th, True]` returns an `Association` containing auxiliary data helpful in analyzing rational approximations of `x/m`.

```
ClearAll[findRationalMultiples];
findRationalMultiples[xm_, smoothing_ : 1, sharpness_ : 5, 
   t_ : Automatic, verbose_ : False] :=
  Module[{x, m, conv, scalederror, data, threshold, res},
   {x, m} = Replace[xm, {y_Real :> {y, 1}}];
   x = x/m;
   res = <||>;
   res["Convergents"] = Convergents[x];
   res["ScaledError"] = Abs@(x - res["Convergents"])*
     Denominator[res["Convergents"]]^2;
   data = -RealExponent@res["ScaledError"];
   threshold = 
    t /. {Automatic -> -Max@data/3, Scaled[s_] :> -s*Max@data};
   res["Peaks"] = PeakDetect[data, smoothing, sharpness, threshold];
   res["Answers"] = 
    m*Extract[res["Convergents"], Position[res["Peaks"], 1]];
   If[verbose,
    res["SmoothData"] = GaussianFilter[data, {3, smoothing}];
    res,
    res["Answers"]
    ]
   ];
```

Example: A rational multiple of `Pi`.  You need enough `digits` to make a good approximation, and we set the working precision with `SetPrecision` a bit higher so that `Convergents[]` doesn't quit too soon.

```
digits = 15. + Log10[33000^2];
x = SetPrecision[
   Round[29/33000 Pi, 2^-Ceiling[Log2[10^digits]]],
   100];
findRationalMultiples[{x, Pi}]

(*  {(29 π)/33000}  *)
```

`Rationalize` fails on this example:

```
Rationalize[x/Pi]

(*  0.000878787878787878787878773416025526...  *)
```

---

OP's main question.  The function `findRationalMultiples` fails to find a rational multiple of `Pi`.  We asked for the verbose association, so that we can examine the details.

```
x = 2.475188114422334324055850325497184848859183731753159368668810119536078273196602710715450734911249987;
frm = findRationalMultiples[{x, Pi}, 1, 5, Automatic, True];

frm@"Answers"
(*  {}  *)
```

A plot of the scaled error shows several peaks, not just one as we would expect for a rational multiple.  Consequently, I think it is likely that the OP's `x` is not a rational multiple of `Pi` or `x` is a bad approximation of the real number it represents.

```
ListLinePlot[RealExponent@frm["ScaledError"][[;; 88]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

---

Numerical caveat: As with most, if not all, numerical routines, it is possible to construct pathological examples that fool the routine.  For instance, `y = Round[Pi, 1/2^b]` will have the same initial convergents as `Pi` until the convergents differ from `Pi` by around `1/2^b` or less.  But `y` is a rational number and `findRationalMultiples[{N@y, 1}]` works up to `b == 27`, returns multiple candidates up to `b == 36`, and returns no solutions for `b >= 37`.

---

**Appendix.**

Well, why not?, the post is already so long....  Here's a slightly different approach to `findRationalMultiples` using *Mathematica's* notion of accuracy to perform the role of `scalederror`.  It also returns an association, with slightly different keys and through `Reap[findRationalMultiples[{x, m}]]`; it uses `Sow` with the tag `findRationalMultiples` if you want to use `Reap` with tags.  Generally, because we increase the precision before calling `Convergents`, we get at least one, and often several, convergents at the end of the `Convergents[]` list whose error is zero at the scaled accuracy; we drop all but the one with the least denominator.

The `Accuracy[]` for comparing the difference of each convergent `p/q` from `x` is set to `-Log10[1/q^2]` plus the parameter `scale`.  The default value `4` corresponds roughly to the constant $c$ used in `Rationalize[x]` (see docs or quote above); however, the behavior here is somewhat different than `Rationalize`.  If `x` is found by rounding an unpathological rational number, then `findRationalMultiples[{x, 1}, s]` should find a single good candidate at both smaller and larger scales.  (The chances of finding more good candidates increases as the scale `s` decreases, and vice versa.) At small enough scales, `findRationalMultiples[{x, 1}, s]` will fail on any `x` probably.
[TBD: Just realized that `trim` needs some adjustment; sometimes the good candidate is adjacent to the bad candidates, but I have to run. Drats.]

```
ClearAll[findRationalMultiples];
findRationalMultiples::mult = "Multiple good candidates found at scale ``; returning first. Use Reap for more information.";
findRationalMultiples::noans = "No good candidates found at scale ``; returning first convergent with zero error. Use Reap for more information.";
findRationalMultiples[xm_, scale_ : 4] :=
  Module[{x, m, conv, trim, zeros, res},
   {x, m} = Replace[xm, {y_Real :> {y, 1}}];
   x = x/m;
   res = <||>;
   res["Convergents"] = Convergents[SetPrecision[x, Infinity]];
   res["Errors"] = MapThread[SetAccuracy,
     {SetPrecision[x, N@Precision[x]] - res["Convergents"],
      scale + 2 Max[5, -Log10[x], #] & /@ 
       Log10@N@Denominator@res["Convergents"]}];
   trim = LengthWhile[Reverse@res["Errors"], # == 0 &];
   (* compare first two zeros to be dropped 
      IF the accuracy jump > Precision[x] or Log10[denominator] >= Precision[x] 
      THEN first one is a good candidate, so decrement trim *)
   If[trim > 1 &&
     Accuracy[res["Errors"][[-trim]]] < Accuracy[res["Errors"][[1 - trim]]] - Precision[x],
    trim--
    ];
   zeros = Position[Drop[res["Errors"], 1 - trim], z_ /; z == 0];
   res["Candidates"] = m*Extract[res["Convergents"], zeros];
   res["Answer"] = Replace[res["Candidates"], {a_, ___} :> a];
   Sow[res, findRationalMultiples];
   Switch[Length@res["Candidates"],
    0 | 1, Message[findRationalMultiples::noans, scale],
    2, Null,
    _, Message[findRationalMultiples::mult, scale]
    ];
   res["Answer"]
   ];
```

My example from above has stable results at different scales:

```
digits = 15. + Log10[33000^2];
x = SetPrecision[
   Round[29/33000 Pi, 2^-Ceiling[Log2[10^digits]]],
   100];
findRationalMultiples[{x, Pi}]
findRationalMultiples[{x, Pi}, 2]
findRationalMultiples[{x, Pi}, 8]
(*
(29 π)/33000
(29 π)/33000
(29 π)/33000
*)
```

Rationalization of the OP's number is unstable with change of scale. The first trial below reproduces one of the other posts' answers, but the instability suggests it's doubtful that `x` came from rounding.

```
x = 2.475188114422334324055850325497184848859183731753159368668810119536078273196602710715450734911249987;
findRationalMultiples[{x, Pi}]

(*  (528518980406819854 π)/670814204566564617  *)

findRationalMultiples[{x, Pi}, 2]
```

> findRationalMultiples::mult :  Multiple good candidates found at scale 2; returning first. Use Reap for more information. >>

```
(*  (105618056127 π)/134054016857  *)

findRationalMultiples[{x, Pi}, 8]
```

> findRationalMultiples::noans :  No good candidates found at scale 8; returning first convergent with zero error. Use Reap for more information.

```
(*  (127783177086971763037570942964097163555065759781296 π) /
      162186739686443508647264007143241471430512176744729         *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
b = (12343556574747/50000) \[Pi];

N[b, 20]/Pi // Rationalize[#, 0] &

(* 12343556574747/50000 *)

Rationalize[(2.\
4751881144223343240558503254971848488591837317531593686688101195360782\
73196602710715450734911249987/Pi), #] & /@ (10^Range[-10, -5])


(* {86111/109295, 24592/31213, 12257/15557, 11711/14864, 8123/10310, \
26/33} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Expansion into a continuous fraction can be used.

In your example

```
a = 2.4751881144223343240558503254971848488591837317531593686688101195\
36078273196602710715450734911249987;
ContinuedFraction[a/\[Pi]]
```

> {0,1,3,1,2,2,472,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,2,4,2,2,2,4,5,243,1,2,6,2,3,1,1,2,1,16,1,24388,1,4,2,2,1,1,1,1,20,2,1,1,6,6,1,3,1,8,1,1,2,5,4,13,1,1,6,3,2,300,6,103,5,2,3,3,2,1,3,1,3,16,2,1,4,1,1,3,34,1}

There is a large element 24388. Dropping all elements starting with it gives

```
b = FromContinuedFraction@{0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 472, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 243, 1, 2, 6, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
   17}
```

$$
\frac{528518980406819854}{670814204566564617}
$$
with error

```
a/\[Pi] - b///N
```

$$\text{9.11146$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-41}$$

If all digits in your number are correct it is not a rational number with a small denominatior. If only 40 digits or so are true then `b` looks like the best candidate. But if only a few digits are true one can take segments up to the previous relatively large numbers, say

```
FromContinuedFraction@{0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2}
```

$$\frac{26}{33}$$